# How to automatically auto play youtube videos?

Tags: automation, safari, youtube

Can I make youtube **always** autoplay videos on page load? I know everyone always wants to stop this it seems... Specifically embedded videos.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#autoplay 
This tells you how to set it up. It also gives even more options of things you can do with embedded videos.

Comment: This seems to be for a website developer, not for the user, am I right? I would like videos on all web pages **I** load to show up this way.

Comment: Ah right, I though you meant in a web developer sense because you mentioned embedded videos. Sorry about that.